# Cross-loading Factor Analysis

Tags: factor-analysis

Using the Pattern Matrix Table on the SPSS I found there are some cross-loading among some of the variables. I am using Promax Rotation of the PCA and got 15 Factors from 56 Variables.

I have 13 variables with some cross-loading of greater than 0.3. Is there a rule of thumb to remove variables that are cross-loading on multiple factors? Any advice as to how one should approach this please?

Here is a snapshot of the specific variables - highlighted in orange are the cross-loadings.

[image: Snapshot from the results]

Comment: "Cross-loading" is an unusual term in factor analysis. (It encounters in discriminant / canonical / some other analyses, not is classic FA.) What do you mean by it?

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you. Excuse my wrong use of terminology. Some Factors show a pattern that was not quite so clear because they load to some meaningful degree on two or more factors. For example under INNER_HARMONY I have .383 and .312. Based on my reading, I have seen in various papers, authors argued that this should not be the case. Statistically speaking how should this be viewd?

Comment: What you imply (and probably want) is "clear structure": item to "belong" ideally to just one, if any, factor. Clear structure is not guaranteed. If you analyze data from, say, well established factor-based questionnaire, it is likely to appear. Otherwise - not.

Comment: But seeng your specific results (table), I wonder: why did you extract and rotated all 16 components? PCA or FA is usually used to reduce the dimensionality. Extract, say, 2 or 3 factors/components, and rotate them.

Comment: @ttnphns Many thanks for point that out. I extracted all the factors because I thought I had to. When I extract 3 components,  get around 35% Cumulative Variance. When I extract all the components (i.e. 16), I get around 66%. For 4 components I get around 39%.  I was led to believe that a figure under 40% is not ideal?! Any ideal approach for this please?